# "/usr/bin/python^M: bad interpreter"

Tags: python, pycharm, interpreter, eof, carriage-return

Cannot figure out, where to change EOF in PyCharm.
My scripts start with :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

It outputs something like this when I try to run it like an executable (`chmode +x`) :

> -bash: ./main.py: /usr/bin/python^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: there seems to be `^M` characters in the script, use dos2unix

Comment: It seems like the original file was created in MSDOS/Windows without UNIX/Linux end of line support. So when you tried to run this file on UNIX/Linux, you got an error.

The easiest way is to recreate the file on UNIX/Linux.

The scalable way is to configure the MSDOS/Windows shell to support saving with UNIX/Linux end of lines. It's help you to create and reuse files on both systems.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Set line separator to **Unix**:

[image: Unix]

Comment: If the file has already been saved, this doesn't seem help. Probably only with new files? You'll need to use the `dos2unix` tool for those files.

Answer (score 55):

The issue is not EOF but EOL. The shell sees a ^M as well as the end of line and thus tries to find `/usr/bin/python^M` .

The usual way of getting into this state is to edit the python file with a MSDOS/Windows editor and then run on Unix. The simplest fix is to run dos2unix on the file or edit the file in an editor that explicitly allows saving with Unix end of lines.

Comment: I think the python interpreter is not ran at all. The shebang interpreter fails on ^M.

Comment: Yes sorry the shell is see ingthis

Comment: If you don't have dos2unix, simply execute `sudo apt-get install dos2unix`, in Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 33):

You may find the answers here: [./configure : /bin/sh^M : bad interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920416/configure-bin-shm-bad-interpreter)

As a Mac OS X user, I didn't find the command `dos2unix`. Alternatively, I use vi/vim: `:set fileformat=unix` and then save the file `:wq`

Answer (score 25):

If you are using Vim, just enter the following command:

```
:set fileformat=unix
```

Answer (score 16):

you may want to try `dos2unix <filename>`

Comment: note. Had centos installed without it. to install just sudo yum install dos2unix. it's in the repos.

Answer (score 11):

Install dos2unix:
**sudo apt-get install dos2unix**

and let it do the magic:
**dos2unix FILENAME**

Answer (score 6):

For MacOS you can install it via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) like this:

```
brew install dos2unix
```

And next do

```
dos2unix FILENAME
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar to Jiangwei Yu's post. On UNIX/Linux, I used vi to edit the Python file. Using vi, you can see the ^M at the end of each line.

Find the following line `/usr/bin/python^M`

Hit `end` to get to the end of the line

Hit `delete` to remove the ^M

To save the file and quit, type in: `:wq`

This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

you may try to do this:

```
sed --in-place 's/^M//g' main.py
```

[ to type in ^M, press ctrl+v,ctrl+m ]

Answer (score 2):

Just a Question of format beween win and unix:

try command: dos2unix fileName

After it run again, it should work

Comment: How does this add to or improve on other answers?