# Making python script executable using anaconda

Tags: terminal, executable

I've written a couple of scripts that I want to run automatically on my computer, so I've added the line `#! Applications/anaconda/bin/python` to the beginning of each script to made it executable. Oddly enough, one of the programs worked perfectly after adding that line and then running `chmod +x \path\to\program.py` in the terminal. But for the second program I followed the same process but when I try and run the script from the terminal using `\path\to\program.py` I get an error which reads:
`Applications/anaconda/bin/python^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`. I understand that this means that I have a carriage return on the end of the line that's throwing it off, but I don't understand how to get rid of it. Here are the snippets from my two scripts, this one works:

```
#! /Applications/anaconda/bin/python


import time
from selenium import webdriver
import easygui
.
.
.
```

And this one doesn't:

```
#! Applications/anaconda/bin/python


from datetime import datetime
import calendar
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more digging. I found that the problem was caused because I had edited the script using both a windows computer and a mac. All that was needed to fix the problem was to copy and paste the code to a new .py file and then it worked like a charm. There are also more technical work arounds here: [PyCharm. /usr/bin/python^M: bad interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975011/pycharm-usr-bin-pythonm-bad-interpreter)

Answer (score 0):

Your second script is missing a "/" at the beginning.

This is, replace `#! Applications/anaconda/bin/python` with `#! /Applications/anaconda/bin/python`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try opening your file using vim and run in command mode

`:set fileformat=unix`