# script for cron.daily

Tags: linux, cron

I need to have my Java program run on a linux box once a day. So I created a simple file with just one line:

```
java -jar /opt/location/my_jar.jar
```

and put it in etc/cron.daily, assuming it would run once a day. But it doesn't run at all. I tried both to have the .sh extension, or simply the file name with no extension. Still, no luck.

I googled it and I'm getting quite a bit of conflicting info. Can someone please help?

EDIT:

I'm summarizing the place it is right now, based on the answers given by Satish and Mithrandir.

1.I created the run_conversions script using vi, to get over the problem with the end of line character on windows. Now the script is

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/java -jar /opt/location/my_jar.jar
```

2.I put it in /etc/cron.hourly.

3.Checking the log at /var/log/cron I'm seeing the it's starting run_conversions and finishing run_conversions every hour. So far so good.

4.But it doesn't seem like my jar file is running. I know this because when it's running properly it should update a database -- and the database is not updating.

5.Here's the strange thing: when I'm running cron.hourly manually, but calling

```
run-parts /etc/cron.hourly
```

the jar file is hit propertly, and the database is updating.

To sum it up: when running it through run-parts, it works. When leaving it to run hourly by itself, it doesn't.

Any ideas?

EDIT 2:

Following advice from Satish, Mithrandir and vahid I changed my run_conversions_loc to look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bexport SHELL=/bin/bash
/usr/bin/java -jar /opt/tf/conversions/aff_networks2.jar > /opt/tf/conversions/runconversions.txt
```

I removed the script from cron.hourly and added this line to crontab:

```
*/10 * * * * /opt/tf/conversions/run_conversions_loc
```

The script now runs every 10 minutes, and is registered in the cron log like this:

```
Feb 24 09:30:01 backsome CROND[7933]: (root) CMD (/opt/tf/conversions/run_conversions_loc)
```

So far it looks good. But the database -- which it should update -- isn't updated.

Looking deeper into it, the jar file, aff_networks2.jar is looking for an `ftr.properties` file in the local directory -- the same directory where it's at. The file exists in this directory. But it's not read properly. I know this because in the output file, runconversions.txt, the value that should be read from the properties file is null.

Two things to complete the picture:

1. Everything in the conversions directory has 777 permissions. I know it's not recommended to give such extended permissions but I wanted to make sure (at least try) it's not the issue.
2. When I run the script from the shell by calling `./run_conversions_loc` it runs, finds the properties file, and updates the database. I am logged into the shell as root, and I also created all the relevant files as root, and installed as root the line for calling the script in crontab.

Any ideas why isn't cron reading the properties file?

Comment: did you check /var/log/cron ?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Satish. I checked it now and my script isn't mentioned there, although now I put it both in cron.daily and cron.hourly, and followed Mithrandir advice below. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Do I need to do an "install' of my script, when I'm dropping it in cron.daily, or cron.hourly?

Comment: create a shell script like @Mithrandir told and run cron manually on command like: run-parts /etc/cron.daily  and check your log

Comment: Thanks, Satish. I did what you said and I'm running cron.hourly manually and getting this error:  Unable to access jarfile /opt/location/myjar2.jar. The file exists there, and has execute permissions for owner and group. I'm logged in as root. Why doesn't it run?

Comment: did you run command manually on command line?

Comment: Yes, I did. Something strange is going on. I also tried to run the script directly from the location where it -- and the jar files -- are at, and I'm getting an Unable to access jarfile myjar2.jar. The thing is, it worked fine yesterday when I run it like this. Looks like I'm in a total mess.

Comment: Adding one more thing: when I'm accessing the jar file directly from the command line, java -jar myjar2.jar everything works fine.

Comment: And I guess one more thing: when I'm adding this line #!/bin/sh so the script looks just like Mithrandir's below, I'm getting a "/bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory" error. When I'm removing the line, I'm getting the "Unable to access jarfile myjar2.jar" error.

Comment: To complete the info: when I'm running run-parts /etc/cron.daily like Satish advised the cron is running my script, and it's showing in the log, and the jar file isn't accessed -- as I detailed in the comments above.

Comment: what is your OS? and shell use are using? try #!/bin/bash  one more thing also use full path instead of java. use /usr/bin/java wherever your java located.

Comment: Same error with #!/bin/bash: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory. I changed to full path for java, /usr/bin/java but no luck. The OS is a linux through rackspace.

Comment: Ah! got it is your editor issue, try this command: dos2unix scriptname.sh also check more detail here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920416/configure-bin-shm-bad-interpreter

Comment: Check my complete answer!!! in answer section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its probably your environment variables

does it work as the current user logged in  when executing the script ?

if so

run:

```
env|egrep "(^PATH=|^SHELL=)"|awk '{print "export "$1}'
```

then take the output and put it on the top of your script and try another cron in 2 minutes from now to see if it worked

**Updated answer in response to Eddy's Comment 24th Feb 2013.**

I want to give you a crash course on crontab.

1. setting up crontab can be done via global /etc/crontab or under user as crontab -e (to edit specific user's cron) or crontab -l (lists - stored in /var/spool/cron for each user)

I see you are trying to attempt a run ever 10 minutes which is fine in /etc/crontab

The reason why I suggested giving the entire class path of your current shell is because most of the time the script is trying to use a unix command that is not available as part of the crontab's PATH (which resides right at the very top of /etc/crontab file itself)

To debug path issues its usually a good idea to watch the mailbox of the user that crontab is executing the task as :
so tail -100 /var/spool/mail/root and looking out for any messages related to that cron task as well as the cron logs itself as someone has suggested -

I do not think your problem is paths here though..

You are trying to run a java jar file and it may be that your jar file needs other files in that conversion folder and that when you are running it you are already in that folder....

so in your script you could run

```
cd /opt/tf/conversions/;
 /usr/bin/java -jar aff_networks2.jar > /opt/tf/conversions/runconversions.txt
```

But since this is such a small script you could get away with placing the entire thing as a cron entry and bypassing a shell script altogether something like this

```
*/10 *    * * *   root cd /opt/tf/conversions/; /usr/bin/java -jar aff_networks2.jar > /opt/tf/conversions/runconversions.txt
```

Hope this helps solve this issue

Comment: This is the output: export SHELL=/bin/bash
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
But what does it mean? And should I put it BEFORE or AFTER the line that says #!/bin/sh
?

Comment: this is your current path and your current shell as the user you are logged in as. Put it after #!/bin/sh. This will then export out the same paths within your script running as part of cron. If this works you could look at the top few lines of your crontab file and ensure the path matches or has the missing path that is listed in your current path - which makes the script work whilst you are logged in but not whilst running in crontab

Comment: I acted on your advice, and edited the question with some more info (EDIT 2.) Would be great if you could take a look.

Comment: Thank you very much, vahid. You got it!

Answer (score 3):

Solution with example:

Run command manually on command line:

```
[root@04 cron.daily]# /usr/bin/java -jar /root/HelloWorld.jar
Hello World #1
```

Let create a script in /`etc/cron.daily/test.sh` and give execute permission:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/java -jar /root/HelloWorld.jar
```

**Notes:** run `dos2unix` in case you have dos character issue or error `/bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

```
[root@04 cron.daily]# unix2dos test.sh
unix2dos: converting file test.sh to DOS format ...
```

Test it, voila!!

```
[root@04 cron.daily]# run-parts /etc/cron.daily
/etc/cron.daily/ldiscan:

kcore: Value too large for defined data type
/etc/cron.daily/test.sh:

Hello World #1
```

Comment: Thank you, Satish. You got me closer, it seams, but still not entirely there. I edited my question with more info.

Comment: Lets put that script in crontab with * * * * * <script name>

Comment: Satish can you elaborate? I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: run "crontab -e" command and add line * * * * * /path/of/your/run_conversions  check help here http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/

Comment: I acted on your advice, and edited the question with some more info (EDIT 2.) Would be great if you could take a look.

Comment: Why don't you in script first do cd /path/where/file located and then run jar command. Just add change directory first and run command in that case it will read that file

Answer (score 0):

Change your file to:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/java -jar /opt/location/my_jar.jar
```

Check if `/usr/bin/java` is actually where the command is istalled (`which java`).
Change the permissions of you file to be executable:

```
chmod +x /opt/location/my_jar.jar
```

Comment: Thanks, Mithrandir. I'll try that. Does it matter anything if the extension if .sh, or no extension?

Comment: the first line defines the script and not .sh or .whatever i.e. you could call it script.something and so long as the shell is set on the top line of the script it will work

Comment: It actually matters -- at least on debian, cron.daily is run by run-parts(8), which will skip filenames containing a dot

Comment: I edited the question with some more info (EDIT 2.) Would be great if you could take a look.