# How to build FFmpeg 2.0 for android on linux?

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg

I have downloaded and extracted android-ndk-r9 on my Ubuntu11.04. I want to build FFmpeg latest version which I have downloaded [from here](http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html)
 using git. I followed the procedure described [here](http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-for-android/). I have replaced [this](http://roman10.net/src/build_android_r5b.txt) script suggested there with [this](http://pastebin.com/KKH0dEju). But I got the following error:

[image]

How to resolve this issue or can you suggest me a better approach ?

Comment: Did u manage to fix this issue? Please let me know. Am stuck with the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Either in ./build_android.sh or in ./configure you have an extra **^M**. Open the files with **vi** and clean them from this garbage, see [./configure : /bin/sh^M : bad interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920416/configure-bin-shm-bad-interpreter)

Comment: It's in `./configure` (see the first error line). You can also use `sed` to remove it: `sed -i 's/\r//' configure`