# Cakephp Cake command returns No such file or directory

Tags: cakephp, cmd, ubuntu-12.04

I have been using the cake command on my linux server for 2 years. but now im trying to move to a new server and some how the cake command gives back the error: No such file or directory

even if i give the entire path to the cake command file chmod 777 it stil wont work.

Comment: add exactly what you're doing and exactly what happens to the question (i.e. copy and paste the console output).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution: All I had to do is use the program dos2unix the cake file for CakePHP 2.4.2 has wrong endings when you download it with Ubuntu 13.10

I used the following command:

```
sudo dos2unix /path/to/cake/lib/Cake/Console/cake
```

Comment: This doesn't seem likely (and you wouldn't need to use sudo to run it)

Comment: I spoke with some developers from cakePHP they have seen this problem before with other people. And yes you could run it without sudo I however have it installed with sudo.

Comment: My development environment is a Windows machine, and when I deliver the code to a Linux box, I need to dos2unix (and give execute permissions) to Console/cake.

Answer (score 4):

I also have this problem on some servers and never figured out why this happened. I suspect the so called "shebang" might not be set correctly for every Linux distribution (e.g. if the cake script stars with `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, but you don't use bash on your server or your distribution doesn't have the env binary in that path, it might fail on that. This is just a theory though, as I said I never really figured it out, nor did I invest much time in investigating.

Although, what I always use as a fallback is simply calling the cake.php script (from the app folder) instead, like:

```
php Console/cake.php -app `pwd` bake
```

That never lets me down. The `-app pwd` bit is to tell the shell that your current directory is your app directory, so the shell can find all your files.

Comment: I solved the problem but thank you for taking the time to answer this hellish question :-)

Comment: the only answer that really makes sense

Answer (score 4):

The REAL solution to this is to change the End-of-Line (EOL) characters to Unix format, instead of MsDos. So I guess this error will only occur if you worked in Windows.

Anyway, teh mighty
SOLUTION:

**(1)** Open *app/Console/cake* file using any text editor that allows changing of EOL characters e.g. NotePad++.

**(2)** In NotePad++ click:
*Edit -> EOL Conversion -> Convert to Unix format*

**(3)** Save the file and upload it to the server. Now if you navigate to the CakePHP app directory using command like:

```
cd /usr/share/nginx/html/cakeproject/app
```

...you should be able to run `Console/cake` without any problems and see standard output (basically help commands).

Hope this helped you!

Comment: this worked like a charm. for those who are on Sublime, you can go to File -> Save with encoding -> UTF-8

Comment: Thank you very much, I have been working on CakePHP applications since last 2 years, but never faced this issue. I have worked on heavy CRON tasks, but it was the first time, and your solution worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem as well, but the top answer reminded me of a similar problem I faced before: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5514351/1097483

Basically, instead of using `dos2unix` or installing it, you can open the file in vim, do

```
:set fileformat=unix
```

And save it.

Answer (score -1):

In some versions it's possible to install cake using `sudo apt-get install cakephp-scripts`.

After instalation, you coud access bake anywere simple by typing `bake`