# how to access the cakephp console bluehost?

Tags: cakephp, permissions, console

I'm experiencing a trouble with cakephp console and bluehost. Some months ago I configure permissions on 'Console/cake' folder and I could access to console without problems. Now I'm not able to access. I'm in the 'Console' folder and I run

```
$ ./ cake
```

but I receive this message :

```
$ No such file or directory
```

All permissions are set to 755. I tried also to set permissions to 777 but the result is the same. Have you any idea ? Thx in advance

[EDIT]

I SOLVED --> [Cakephp Cake command returns No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19813818/cakephp-cake-command-returns-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: If you are using version 2.x I would go to your application directory and run `Console/cake`. If you are in Console, try running `cake`. But by convention you should run any console commands from your application directory. Also it seems that you have a space before cake on your current command. Try `./cake`.

Comment: Same proplem friend , but I SOVED following this --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19813818/cakephp-cake-command-returns-no-such-file-or-directory .