# Linux rpmbuild temporary file error

Tags: centos, rpmbuild

When runnig rpmbuild with command

```
rpmbuild -v -ba --sign --clean ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/myspecfile.spec
```

I get this output:

```
Enter pass phrase:  
Pass phrase is good.  
Executing(%prep): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.6akVI6  
+ umask 022  
+ cd /home/rpmbuilder/rpmbuild/BUILD  
+ LANG=C  
+ export LANG  
+ unset DISPLAY  
+ $'\r'  
**: command not foundwXWF: line 30:**  
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.6akVI6 (%prep)
```

So I edited the temporary file **/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.6akVI6**, searched line 30, and found a single character there:
**^M**

If I execute the temporary file I get the same error, but it executes the all lines after 30, unlike the rpmbuild that breaks on that line and doesn't continue executing:

sudo sh /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.6akVI6

```
+ umask 022  
+ cd /home/rpmbuilder/rpmbuild/BUILD  
+ LANG=C  
+ export LANG  
+ unset DISPLAY  
+ $'\r'  
**: command not foundkVI6: line 30:**  
+ cd /home/rpmbuilder/rpmbuild/BUILD  
+ rm -rf mysource-1.0.0  
+ /usr/bin/gzip -dc /home/rpmbuilder/rpmbuild/SOURCES/mysource-1.0.0.tar.gz  
+ /bin/tar -xvvf -  
drwxrwxrwx 0/0               0 2014-11-04 17:10 mysource-1.0.0/  
+ STATUS=0  
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'  
+ cd mysource-1.0.0  
+ /bin/chmod -Rf a+rX,u+w,g-w,o-w .  
+ exit 0
```

If I edit the file and remove line 30 (**^M**) I am able to run the script with no errors:

```
sudo sh /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.6akVI6  
+ umask 022  
+ cd /home/rpmbuilder/rpmbuild/BUILD  
+ LANG=C  
+ export LANG  
+ unset DISPLAY  
+ cd /home/rpmbuilder/rpmbuild/BUILD  
+ rm -rf mysource-1.0.0   
+ /usr/bin/gzip -dc /home/rpmbuilder/rpmbuild/SOURCES/mysource-1.0.0.tar.gz
+ /bin/tar -xvvf -  
drwxrwxrwx 0/0               0 2014-11-04 17:10 mysource-1.0.0/  
+ STATUS=0  
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
+ cd mysource-1.0.0  
+ /bin/chmod -Rf a+rX,u+w,g-w,o-w .  
+ exit 0
```

This suggests me that the rpmbuild is being stopped because of that single character on line 30.

Any hints why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920416/configure-bin-shm-bad-interpreter)
It seems that files saved on windows, get that character, it is a DOS line ending.
I had my spec file created on windows, so I edited it and did the suggested commands:

```
:set fileformat=unix
```

and re-ran rpmbuild and it worked.