# ./configure step in Installing qt

Tags: c++, xml, qt

I am trying to install Qt on my Ubuntu Linux for using its libraries in reading XML files. I downloaded it from [Qt Submodules](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.4/5.4.1/submodules/) and started to install step by step according the instruction in the [Qt for Linux/X11 - Building from Source](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-building.html) web page.

Things when well until I issued `./configure` at the step 3. Then this error is appeared:

```
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

These are my code lines:

```
cd /tmp
gunzip qt-everywhere-opensource-src-%VERSION%.tar.gz        # uncompress the archive
tar xvf qt-everywhere-opensource-src-%VERSION%.tar          # unpack it
cd /tmp/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-%VERSION%
   ./configure
```

I am confused that what should I do? I can not find configure...

Thanks in advance for your helpful answers.

Comment: Dumb question.... Is there a `configure` file? Post the results of `ls -al | grep -i config`.

Comment: It sounds like you may be in the wrong directory. Try a `find . -iname configure` to locate it.

Comment: again same, nothing happens, still my command line is in the above directory :(

Comment: It sounds like you are in the wrong directory or the unpack of the archive failed (or something else that's non-obvious). Start over, beginning at the download :)

Comment: And, it has to be said, the correct solution to what asker says they want to do, is install the Qt of Ubuntu. One might still want to install latest Qt Creator instead of the Ubuntu's default one, but unless there is an actual reason to want a newer Qt, using the one packed by distro is good for actually getting some problem solved. Deployment is so much easier when the libraries are provided by the OS.

Answer (score 2):

From the official website:

> If you download a Zip source package, you will need to convert Windows-style line endings (CR/LF) to Unix-style line-endings (LF) when you uncompress the package. To do this, give the "-a" option when you run the "unzip' command.If you fail to supply the "-a" option when unzipping the package, you will see the following error message when you attempt to execute the configure command: "bash: ./configure: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory"

So be sure to supply the -a option when uzipping 
Take a look at this link: http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/2920416/configure-bin-shm-bad-interpreter

Answer (score 2):

For those who came into this question with same answer, but for Qt5..

> From the official website:
>
> > If you download a Zip source package, you will need to convert
> >      Windows-style line endings (CR/LF) to Unix-style line-endings (LF)
> >      when you uncompress the package. To do this, give the "-a" option when
> >      you run the "unzip' command.If you fail to supply the "-a" option when
> >      unzipping the package, you will see the following error message when
> >      you attempt to execute the configure command: "bash: ./configure:
> >      /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory"
>
> So be sure to supply the -a option when uzipping Take a look at this
>    link:
>    http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/2920416/configure-bin-shm-bad-interpreter

This answer does not work anymore, becouse all files in zip archive are tagged as binary (even configure text files). Only way to make it work is download xxx.tar.xz file, and open it by `tar -xf xxx.tar.xz`. If TAR.XZ file is not recognized, use -J parameter (`tar -xJf xxx.tar.xz`).

Comment: Tested on Centos7  with Qt5.9.4, this solution works as expected: using the tar.xz was the key.