# I am deploying with 'eb deploy' in aws but getting the following error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using 'eb deploy' for deploying my commits but getting this error

> WARNING: You have uncommitted changes.
>       Creating application version archive "6fea".
>       Uploading: [##################################################] 100% Done...
>       INFO: Environment update is starting.
>       INFO: Deploying new version to instance(s).
>       ERROR: [Instance: i-10d1f9ec] Command failed on instance. Return code: 126
>   Output: /bin/sh: ./scripts/update-ftp-dns.sh: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory.
>       container_command 07-update_ftp_dns in .ebextensions/03-vsftpd.config failed.  For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
>       INFO: Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
>       INFO: New application version was deployed to running EC2 instances.
>       ERROR: Update environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation.

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Can you show us your sciripts: ebextensions/03-vsftpd.config and how this is created: update-ftp-dns.sh

Answer (score 0):

The error message is a bit hidden, but it's in there:

> Output: **/bin/sh**: ./scripts/update-ftp-dns.sh: **/bin/sh^M**: bad interpreter: No such file or directory.

If I had to guess, you have a line break with both a line feed and a carriage return in it. It's treating the carriage return character as if it's part of the name of the executable.

Make sure that you've converted the /scripts/update-ftp-dns.sh script so that it uses Unix line endings only.

See [./configure : /bin/sh^M : bad interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920416/configure-bin-shm-bad-interpreter)

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar, and the cause was having Git's [autocrlf](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/) value set to true. What this means is that Git will convert the file to a Windows-formatted one when `git checkout` is run - which unfortunately means that the Elastic Beanstalk tool tries to upload Windows-formatted files to your Linux server, which will manifest in errors like this.

I fixed it by switching autoclrf to false, and committing the relevant file again. Do be aware of the repercussions of this however.