# Error when installing Cocoapods in React Native project

Tags: xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I was trying to install manually CocoaPods into my React Native project

1. Fix command-line tools path in XCode.
2. Manually created ios folder in the project directory.
3. Manually install CocoaPods, but this is the error I got:

   ```
   [!] /bin/bash -c 
   set -e
   #!/bin/bash

   set -e

   PLATFORM_NAME="${PLATFORM_NAME:-iphoneos}"
   CURRENT_ARCH="${CURRENT_ARCH}"

   if [ -z "$CURRENT_ARCH" ] || [ "$CURRENT_ARCH" == "undefined_arch" ]; then
       # Xcode 10 beta sets CURRENT_ARCH to "undefined_arch", this leads to incorrect linker arg.
       # it's better to rely on platform name as fallback because architecture differs between simulator and device

       if [[ "$PLATFORM_NAME" == *"simulator"* ]]; then
           CURRENT_ARCH="x86_64"
       else
           CURRENT_ARCH="armv7"
       fi
   fi

   export CC="$(xcrun -find -sdk $PLATFORM_NAME cc) -arch $CURRENT_ARCH -isysroot $(xcrun -sdk $PLATFORM_NAME --show-sdk-path)"
   export CXX="$CC"

   # Remove automake symlink if it exists
   if [ -h "test-driver" ]; then
       rm test-driver
   fi

   ./configure --host arm-apple-darwin

   # Fix build for tvOS
   cat << EOF >> src/config.h
   /* Add in so we have Apple Target Conditionals */
   #ifdef __APPLE__
   #include <TargetConditionals.h>
   #include <Availability.h>
   #endif
   /* Special configuration for AppleTVOS */
   #if TARGET_OS_TV
   #undef HAVE_SYSCALL_H
   #undef HAVE_SYS_SYSCALL_H
   #undef OS_MACOSX
   #endif
   /* Special configuration for ucontext */
   #undef HAVE_UCONTEXT_H
   #undef PC_FROM_UCONTEXT
   #if defined(__x86_64__)
   #define PC_FROM_UCONTEXT uc_mcontext->__ss.__rip
   #elif defined(__i386__)
   #define PC_FROM_UCONTEXT uc_mcontext->__ss.__eip
   #endif
   EOF

   # Prepare exported header include
   EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR="exported/glog"
   mkdir -p exported/glog
   cp -f src/glog/log_severity.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
   cp -f src/glog/logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
   cp -f src/glog/raw_logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
   cp -f src/glog/stl_logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
   cp -f src/glog/vlog_is_on.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"

   /bin/bash: ./configure: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
   ```

Comment: Check the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57395463/react-native-glog-ios-unknown-type-name-start-google-namespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the file node_modules/react-native/scripts/ios-configure-glog.sh in Sublime Text editor, change the line endings with View > Line Endings > Mac OS 9, save and try pod install, it works. Note: It doesn't works when you change to Unix line endings so must to Mac OS 9 in sublime text or some equivalent mac line ending from other tools.

If you want a better solution or more info on the problem, please see https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28217.